# MPMusicPlayerController buffering / preloading

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, mpmediaplayercontroller

Is there a way to make MPMusicPlayerController buffer content before I call -play? Or does it do this by default when you set a queue? AVAudioPlayer has the -prepareToPlay method and I've heard that AVQueuePlayer starts buffering the next item automatically, but does MPMusicPlayerController have the same behaviour?

Comment: yes if AVQueuePlayer starts buffering the next item automatically then so does MPMusicPlayerController  as both have queue functionality

Comment: Have you observed this behaviour for sure, or is it just a guess?

Comment: i not observed this behaviour. i guessed

Comment: This is related to my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31520681/mpmusicplayercontroller-does-not-prepare-preload-correct/54609102#54609102

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this question is in the iOS 6 beta docs, if anyone is wondering. Can't say much more because of NDA.

**EDIT:** As requested, since the NDA has been lifted, here's the answer: As of iOS 6, `MPMusicPlayerController`, like `MPMoviePlayerController` implements the [MPMediaPlayback](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMediaPlayback_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/MPMediaPlayback) protocol, which has methods like `-prepareToPlay`.